# using unicode in rewriterule

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have used the following statements in `.htaccess` file which contains utf8 characters in `RewriteRule`. `.htaccess` file is saved in notepad with utf8 encoding. All pages of site are saved in utf8 and charset of all is utf8.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /new/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^هاستینگ/هاست-لینوکس-عادی/$ /linux-regular.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But when I browse to the URL `هاستینگ/هاست-لینوکس-عادی/` simply I get Not Found error.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @ Michael: the rewrite rule doesn't work

Comment: Sorry for inomplete post :( But when I browse to the url هاستینگ/هاست-لینوکس-عادی/ simply I get Not Found error.

Comment: If you saved it in "notepad" (I assume you meant "notepad", not "notepas" and I can only wonder why you would use that) then it will automatically add a ".txt" extension, which you need to remove before the file can even be used. Make sure you're not using the Windows default folder settings, which hide the extension of "known files".

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> RewriteBase /new/
> :
> RewriteRule ^هاستینگ/هاست-لینوکس-عادی/$ /linux-regular.php [L]
> ```

The fact that you have set a specific value for the `RewriteBase`, yet specified a root-relative URL path in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* raises alarm bells. The `RewriteBase` directive only effects *relative* (not starting with a slash or scheme) path *substitutions*, so in this case, it will simply be ignored - which I'm sure is not the intention - otherwise, there would be no need to set it in the first place.

By removing the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *substitution* then it will take into account the `RewriteBase` and will be rewritten to `/new/linux-regular.php`. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^هاستینگ/هاست-لینوکس-عادی/$ linux-regular.php [L]
```

Which is consistent with your later comment: "...and removed / from start of linux-regular.php and it worked."

> ...the special characters will be encoded in %xx hex form

*Aside:* Whilst the request should be %-encoded (URL encoded), the URL-path that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against is %-decoded (URL decoded) by the rewrite engine. So, using the actual (UTF-8) characters in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is correct here (contrary to the other answer).

If you specifically needed to match against the the %-encoded URL-path then you would need to use a `RewriteCond` directive and check against `THE_REQUEST` server variable.

Answer (score 0):

URLs are "on the wire" encoded in plain ASCII (latin1) - all non ASCII chars are encoded by clients (browsers) in `%xx` hex format...

You can find the following [article](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) helpful.

To be more specific: your Apache config file will be plain ASCII text and the special characters will be encoded in `%xx` hex form - you can even translate it using a simple tool available on the above referenced w3schools page.

Comment: I just kept utf8 characters and removed / from start of linux-regular.php and it worked. It was looking into root of site but am linking from a directory and target is in the same directory. Internet has changed. browsers and servers understand unicode urls. Now I added RewriteRule ^*/css/(.*)$ css/$1 [L] and am getting Internet Server Error. Whats wrong with it?

Comment: you're wrong about the URL encoding - there are two RFCs [1738](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) and [2396](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) specifying URL encoding I'm aware of and I don't see any sign about nonASCII characters (seems apache is smart enough to understand it and recode UTF to quoted before compare). To your question - your regular expression is wrong - you cannot specify 0 - n occurrences of start of string as you do by ^* ...

Comment: Whilst the URL in the request is URL encoded (ie. %-encoded), the URL-path that the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ matches against is %-decoded.